Does commenting in a thread cause it to move to the top of some 'questions/answers stream/list'?
I commented an answer in the "What data sources are available online?"-thread (What data sources are available online?). But will that only show to the one who wrote the answer I commented (as a notification) or will the whole thread move up to the top of some list/stream when there's activity in it (like in a forum).
Why I wonder is because my comment was more of a question (related to 'the answer') that I'd like to be answered rather than a comment. 
Hopefully I'm not too confusing.

Your comment will not "bump" the original question; only the person whose answer you commented on will get a notification.
If you want to ask a public question, then ask a public question.

Okey, thank you!
